# Why does my service worker in my PWA work fine when online but break when offline (built with Parcel.js)?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, parceljs

### The question

My service worker installs, and fetches files from the Cache Storage, perfectly when online.

But as soon as I go offline it can't find anything. What am I doing wrong please?

Perhaps I'm loading things in the wrong order. Or using `async` incorrectly in my main js file. Or Parcel's list of files to cache in the `manifest` is insufficient.

### The code

Here's my `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Journal</title>      
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="hsl(45, 100%, 50%)">
        <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"  content="hsl(45, 100%, 50%)">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/img/logo.svg">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="manifest" href="./app.webmanifest">
    </head>

    <body onload="document.body.style.visibility=`visible`;">
        <!-- avoid flash of unstyled content -->
        <script>document.body.style.visibility=`hidden`;</script>
        <div class="app">
        </div>
        <script src="main.ts" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My `main.ts` file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import {router} from './js/4_widgets/router';
import appWidget from './js/4_widgets/app.vue';
import * as storeHelper from './js/3_io/storeHelper';
import * as globalState from './js/2_logic/state';
import * as testData from './js/1_data/testData';
import * as browserStore from './js/3_io/browserStore';

setupApp();

async function setupApp()
{
    globalThis.__VUE_OPTIONS_API__ = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") as unknown as string; //todo make this prod eventually
    globalThis.__VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") as unknown as string;

    await registerServiceWorker();
    await storeHelper.start();

    createApp(appWidget)
        .use(router)
        .mount(`.app`);
}

async function registerServiceWorker(): Promise<void>
{
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
    {
        try
        {
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(new URL('./serviceWorker.ts', import.meta.url), {type: 'module', scope: '/' });
            console.log('Service worker registered', registration);
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            console.error('Error registering service worker:', error);
        }
    }
    else console.warn('Service workers are not supported.');
}
```

and my `serviceWorker.ts` file:

```js
/// <reference types="serviceworker" />

import {manifest, version} from '@parcel/service-worker';

self.addEventListener('offline', (event: Event) =>
{
    console.log('Offline!');
});

self.addEventListener('install', async (event: ExtendableEvent) =>
{
    try
    {
        const cache = await caches.open(version);
        // console.dir(manifest);
        await cache.addAll(manifest); // cache the application's resources.
        await self.skipWaiting(); //makes this serviceworker active immediately
        console.log('Service worker installed');
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.error('Service worker installation failed:', error);
    }
});

self.addEventListener('activate', async (event: Event) =>
{
    const keys = await caches.keys();
    await Promise.all(
        keys.map(key => key !== version && caches.delete(key)) //delete old caches if new version found
    );
    console.log('Service worker activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event: FetchEvent) =>
{
    try
    {
        console.log(`${event.request.method} - ${event.request.url} - request received and we are online: ${navigator.onLine}`);
        if (event.request.method !== "GET")  // Always fetch non-GET requests from the network
            return fetch(event.request);
        const response: Response | undefined = await caches.match(event.request); // If the request is for an asset that is cached, serve it from the cache.
        if (!response)
            console.warn(`${event.request.method} - ${event.request.url} - was NOT found in the cache`);
        console.log(`${event.request.method} - ${event.request.url} - was found in the cache`);
        if (response)
            return response;
        if (navigator.onLine)
        {
            console.log(`${event.request.method} - ${event.request.url} - we are online, so trying to connect...`);
            return fetch(event.request);
        }
        console.error(`${event.request.method} - ${event.request.url} - is not in cache and we are offline`);
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.error('Service worker fetch failed:', error);
    }
});
```

### The debug trail

Here's what happens in the console when I browse to `localhost:1234` in Brave:

First page load, installation works:

```
Service worker registered ServiceWorkerRegistration {installing: ServiceWorker, waiting: null, active: null, navigationPreload: NavigationPreloadManager, scope: 'http://localhost:1234/', …}
serviceWorker.ts:32 Service worker activated
serviceWorker.ts:18 Service worker installed
```

Page refresh, cache items fetched (but note it doesn't try to fetch index.html from the cache, which I thought it should):

```
GET - http://localhost:1234/index.34df27b5.css - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:641 GET - http://localhost:1234/index.b7a05eb9.js - request received and we are online: true
serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:645 GET - http://localhost:1234/index.b7a05eb9.js - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:641 GET - http://localhost:1234/logo.92616178.svg - request received and we are online: true
serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:641 GET - http://localhost:1234/app.webmanifest - request received and we are online: true
serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:645 GET - http://localhost:1234/logo.92616178.svg - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:645 GET - http://localhost:1234/app.webmanifest - was found in the cache
main.ts:39 Service worker registered ServiceWorkerRegistration {installing: ServiceWorker, waiting: null, active: ServiceWorker, navigationPreload: NavigationPreloadManager, scope: 'http://localhost:1234/', …}
:1234/serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:641 GET - http://localhost:1234/appIcon512.7b148678.png - request received and we are online: true
:1234/serviceWorker.js?1684145072288:645 GET - http://localhost:1234/appIcon512.7b148678.png - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.ts:32 Service worker activated
serviceWorker.ts:18 Service worker installed
```

Go offline and refresh (noticed here the Cache Storage is now empty, but apparently that is actually not true: [Cache Storage created by service worker disappears after going offline and refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621623/cache-storage-created-by-service-worker-disappears-after-going-offline-and-refre)), cache items not found. And the `navigator.online` property isn't set to false:

```
bug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ VM11:161
serviceWorker.ts:39 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - request received and we are online: true
serviceWorker.ts:44 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - was NOT found in the cache
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.ts:44
serviceWorker.ts:45 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.ts:50 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - we are online, so trying to connect...
serviceWorker.ts:51     Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at serviceWorker.ts:51:20
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.ts:51
serviceWorker.ts:39 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - request received and we are online: true
serviceWorker.ts:44 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - was NOT found in the cache
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.ts:44
serviceWorker.ts:45 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.ts:50 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - we are online, so trying to connect...
serviceWorker.ts:51     Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at serviceWorker.ts:51:20
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.ts:51
serviceWorker.ts:39 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - request received and we are online: true
serviceWorker.ts:44 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - was NOT found in the cache
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.ts:44
serviceWorker.ts:45 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - was found in the cache
serviceWorker.ts:50 GET - http://localhost:1234/ - we are online, so trying to connect...
serviceWorker.ts:51     Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at serviceWorker.ts:51:20
```

(If I set my browser to `http://localhost:1234/index.html` instead, the service worker says the file is found, but no other code fires and the page is not displayed on the screen).

Refresh again, everything's dead:

```
bug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fetch event handler isn't actually calling `event.respondWith()`. Just returning the Response from your event handler does nothing.